# Análise em tempo real

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Sempre que abro a página de análise tenho que ficar atualizando para poder visualizar algo novo.

Não seria interessante faze-la exibir os dados em tempo real? Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Vocês podem tentar usar Ajax. :P

Comment: @gustavox faltou você pedir um RegEx para resolver o problema, e com jQuery.  Mas desde que o lado do servidor seja feito em PHP com OOP. Ah, e não se esqueça do Bootstrap pra resolver todos os problemas de layout. :P (não resisti, depois que eu reli melhor seu 1o comment, gostei do sarcasmo)

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o que pede é algo relacionado a funcionalidade do site, mas muitas coisas são inviaveis, no entanto você fazer o uso da extensão/plugin greasemonkey:

- Chrome:

  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo
- Firefox:

  https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Então irá verificar se esta na página `http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review` e adicionar um reload (isto é apenas um exemplo de script, você pode fazer a maneira que quiser usando o javascript que será injetado):

```
(function () {
    var minutos = 1;

    if (String(window.location).indexOf("http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review") === 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload();
        } , 1000 * minutos);
    }
})();
```

Se usar os "options" e configurar as urls, o `String(window.location).indexOf` será redundante, mas ainda sim você pode mante-lo.

> Observação: Script testado aqui, tiver problemas me comunique :D